# HTML/CSS text paragraph between image and form

Tags: html, css, forms, image

I have been trying to figure this out now for a while and I think my head will explode if I keep trying to figure it out on my own.

I'm trying to do something very simple, but I had no luck. I am basically trying to have a header and paragraph between an image and a form.

This is what it looks like right now:

[image]

And this is what I'm trying to make it look like:

[image]

And here is the relevant code:
HTML:

```
<div id="content_section4">
    <p><img class="round" src="images/image5.jpg" alt="image1" height=175 width=175/></p>
    <h1 id="connect">Connect</h1>
    <div id="connect">blah blah blha blah joiefje blah blah blahblah blah balah I suck at html I hate my life 
    blah blah blah I have a cat blah blah blah blah blah blah blah eu2398re23ioj</div>

    <!--contact form here-->
    <div id="contact">
        <br>
        <form action="MAILTO:blah@blah.com" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
            <input name="name" type="text" value="Name" size="40" onclick="this.value = '';"/> <br><br>
            <input name="email" type="text" value="Email" size="40" onclick="this.value = '';"/> <br><br>
            <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="33" type="text" style="overflow:auto;resize:none" />Message</textarea> <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Send email"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div><!--end contact_section4-->
```

And the CSS:

```css
#content_section4 {
    float: left;
    text-align: justify;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#content_section4 img {
    float: left;
}

#connect {
    width: 425px;
    padding-left: 205px;
}

#contact {
    float:right;
}

I don't have tons of experience in web design and I have been fussing with this for hours.  Any help is greatly appreciated =)
```

Comment: how wide is the whole container?

Comment: and i realized that was another reason i was running into problems. no more using % for this guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html will be like this..

```
<div id="content_section4">
<div id="content_left">
<p><img class="round" src="images/image5.jpg" alt="image1" height=175 width=175/></p>
<h1 id="connect">Connect</h1>
<div id="connect">blah blah blha blah joiefje blah blah blahblah blah balah I suck at html I hate my life 
blah blah blah I have a cat blah blah blah blah blah blah blah eu2398re23ioj</div>
</div>
<!--contact form here-->
  <div id="contact">
    <br>
    <form action="MAILTO:blah@blah.com" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
        <input name="name" type="text" value="Name" size="40" onclick="this.value = '';"/> <br><br>
        <input name="email" type="text" value="Email" size="40" onclick="this.value = '';"/> <br><br>
        <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="33" type="text" style="overflow:auto;resize:none" />Message</textarea> <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send email"/>
    </form></div>
</div>
```

and your css will be something like this..

```
#content_section4 {
float: left;

text-align: justify;

padding-left: 20px; 

}

#content_section4 img, #content_left {

float: left;

}

#connect {

width: 425px;

padding-left: 205px;

}

#contact {

float:right;    

}
```

Enjoy the fun..

Comment: Thanks! Someone +1 this because I cant =/

Comment: Anything you can suggest to keep the contact form from moving around when the browser window is resized??